How to mask a text that is compatible with PasswordTransformationMethod in android
I have a project that has credit card input but wants to hide the whole text. for example, if the credit card is 1234 1234 1234 1234 then it should be **** **** **** ****. I checked some different ideas just like in here. but it is not compatible with the PasswordTransformationMethod. It only changes everything to *, for example, it used to show  1234 1234 1234 thanks to custom text watcher but when I apply the PasswordTransformationMethod the results become ************ which is not what I expected. I hope someone would be able to help me.

Create your own TransformationMethod that implements the behavior that you seek, where spaces are not replaced by the shrouding character (*).
